# Get shortest path through nodes

Tags: php, nodes

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [V] => Array
        (
            [0] => S
        )

    [L] => Array
        (
            [0] => M
            [1] => Z
            [2] => G
        )

    [S] => Array
        (
            [0] => T
            [1] => X
            [2] => K
        )

    [T] => Array
        (
            [0] => D
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => E
            [1] => N
            [2] => Y
        )

    [W] => Array
        (
            [0] => J
            [1] => Y
        )

    [G] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => K
        )

    [J] => Array
        (
            [0] => T
        )

    [X] => Array
        (
            [0] => H
        )

    [E] => Array
        (
            [0] => Z
        )

    [N] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
        )

    [Z] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => M
        )

    [U] => Array
        (
            [0] => R
        )

    [F] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => V
        )

    [I] => Array
        (
            [0] => F
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [0] => O
            [1] => P
            [2] => T
        )

    [Q] => Array
        (
            [0] => L
            [1] => V
        )

    [Y] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
        )

    [K] => Array
        (
            [0] => T
            [1] => P
            [2] => A
        )

    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => J
        )

    [M] => Array
        (
            [0] => W
        )

    [R] => Array
        (
            [0] => I
        )

    [P] => Array
        (
            [0] => K
            [1] => N
        )

    [O] => Array
        (
            [0] => G
        )

    [H] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q
        )

    [D] => Array
        (
            [0] => U
        )

)
```

Serialized:

```
a:26:{s:1:"V";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"S";}s:1:"L";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"M";i:1;s:1:"Z";i:2;s:1:"G";}s:1:"S";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"T";i:1;s:1:"X";i:2;s:1:"K";}s:1:"T";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"D";}s:1:"B";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"E";i:1;s:1:"N";i:2;s:1:"Y";}s:1:"W";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"J";i:1;s:1:"Y";}s:1:"G";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"A";i:1;s:1:"K";}s:1:"J";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"T";}s:1:"X";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"H";}s:1:"E";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"Z";}s:1:"N";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"B";}s:1:"Z";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"A";i:1;s:1:"M";}s:1:"U";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"R";}s:1:"F";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"C";i:1;s:1:"V";}s:1:"I";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"F";}s:1:"C";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"O";i:1;s:1:"P";i:2;s:1:"T";}s:1:"Q";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"L";i:1;s:1:"V";}s:1:"Y";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"C";}s:1:"K";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"T";i:1;s:1:"P";i:2;s:1:"A";}s:1:"A";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"J";}s:1:"M";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"W";}s:1:"R";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"I";}s:1:"P";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"K";i:1;s:1:"N";}s:1:"O";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"G";}s:1:"H";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"Q";}s:1:"D";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"U";}}
```

This means...

- `V` can go to `S`
- `L` can go to `M`, `Z` and `G`
- `S` can go to `T`, `X` and `K`
- ...

I need an algorithm to find the **shortest way** from `A` to `Z`. This way should be saved as a list of the nodes, something like `AJTDURIFCPNBEZ`.

I just tried it with this recursion:

```
function getWays($key = "A") {
    global $roads;

    echo $key;
    if($key == "Z"){
        echo "<br />";
        return;
    }

    foreach($roads[$key] as $next)
        if($next != "A")
            getWays($next);
}
```

This do not work, it is much more complicate. You have to prevent loops and increase performance (ignore long pathes early, if you already found shorter one).

Can anybody provide help?

Comment: You can use `asort()` function.

Comment: maybe interesting? [The shortest path problem in PHP: demystifying Dijkstra's algorithm](http://odino.org/the-shortest-path-problem-in-php-demystifying-dijkstra-s-algorithm/). Internet search: 'php graph shortest path' returned various links that may give approaches to solving the problem?